# fileinput.Fileinput .read() function for entire file

Tags: python, file-io, replace

Is there a way in fileinput.Fileinput (or some other module/class) where I can read the entire file into memory so I can replace a block of text from the file with a block of text in a list (saved in memory).

There is a .readline function, but I need to find & replace a block of text, and I would prefer not having to zip through the block of text line by line in parallel with zipping through the file.

Comment: Can you use `file.read()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `file` objects have a `read` method that reads the entire file contents into memory.

```
with open("myfile.txt") as infile:
    text = infile.read()

# manipulate text here

with open("myfile.txt", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write(text)
```

Comment: Thanks @kindall, can someone explain to me why the module fileinput is used in the first place?  Is it to work on the file in memory and create a backup file?

Comment: @MikeIssa "This module implements a helper class and functions to quickly write a loop over standard input or a list of files. If you just want to read or write one file see open()." Source: https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html